# Using Enum Name to Get Constants

Tags: java, enums

Sometimes I'm confused that whether I should use enum name to get constants defined in enum. What is the difference between code below and when I should use enum name to obtain constants?

```
switch(accountType) {
    case ZERO_BALANCE:
        break;
    case CREDIT_BALANCE:
        break;
    case DEBIT_BALANCE:
        break;
}

if(accountType == MenuOption.ZERO_BALANCE)
  else if(accountType == MenuOption.CREDIT_BALANCE)
     else if(accountType == MenuOption.DEBIT_BALANCE);
```

Comment: could you please try to be more descriptive of what you are trying to ask. I see people trying to guess the answer only.

Comment: I get my answer, thanks. I will be more descriptive about my questions in future. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `MenuOption.` prefix everywhere, unless

- you have statically imported its constants (which I wouldn't recommend in most cases),
- or you're referring to the constants in a switch statements as in your first snippet.

Answer (score 3):

From the [java nutsandbolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)(emphasis from me)

> Deciding whether to use *if-then-else* statements or a *switch* statement
>   is based on **readability and the expression that the statement is
>   testing**. An if-then-else statement can test expressions based on
>   ranges of values or conditions, whereas a switch statement tests
>   expressions based only on a single integer, enumerated value, or
>   String object.